# Get text after "." using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list like this

```
<ul class="example">
    <li>
        <span class="type"></span>
        <a href="#">New document.txt</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="type"></span>
        <a href="#">Another document.zip</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

How can I get the text after "." and insert to "type"? The result should be like this

```
<ul class="example">
    <li>
        <span class="type">txt</span>
        <a href="#">New document.txt</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="type">zip</span>
        <a href="#">Another document.zip</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. HINT: Post effort and code. You are looking for [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) or [split](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) and [.prev().html(...)](https://api.jquery.com/prev/)

Comment: @Sumitpatel, the previous span contains the type. Look closer

Comment: My code and output doesn't same, you know. The <span> has the text inside.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Iterate over the span and update the text content with the text after the dot(`.`) in the adjacent sibling.

```js
// use text method with callback to iterate and update 
// based on the returned value
$('.example .type').text(function() {
  return $(this)
    // get the a tag
    .next()
    // get text content
    .text()
    // split the text
    .split('.')
    // get the last element from array
    .pop();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="example">
  <li>
    <span class="type"></span>
    <a href="#">New document.txt</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span class="type"></span>
    <a href="#">Another document.zip</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```